# Pandas to_html() col_space arg inputs

Tags: python, html, css, pandas

What are the possible minimum column spacing arguments in CSS spacing units that pandas allows in the method to_html. e.g. `df.to_html(col_space= '10em')` doesn't seem to have an effect at all.

Answer (score 0):

I find it much more effective to explicitly put you CSS into *HTML* document.

```
with open("formatted.html", "w") as f:
    f.write("<h2>Document Name</h2>")
    df.to_html(f, escape=False, index=False)
    f.write("""<style>
        th {text-align: left;}
        h2,table {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
        table {font-size: 0.9em;border-collapse: collapse;}
        </style>""")
```